# log naturalis syntax in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, syntax

I am using Google Earth Engine (JavaScript) to calculate brightness temperature by converting at-satellite radiance of Landsat 8. In literature the formula
`T = K2 / (ln((K1/L)+1) -273.15` (`T`: brightness temperature; `K1,K2`: calibration constants 1 and 2; `L`: at-satellite radiance)
is used.

My code:

```
var bt_calc5 = function(image) {
  var bt_calc = image.expression(
    'K2 / (Math.log(K1 / L + 1) -273.15)', {
      'L' : image.select('TOAThermalRadiance')
    });
  return image.addBands(bt_calc);
};
```

It should add a brightness temperature band to all images of my collection, but results in `Expression parse error` which is why I think the syntax is not correct. I took the `Math.log` expression for logarithmus naturalis from the JavaScript documentation webpage. How do you formulate logarithms in Earth Engine?

Comment: Delete **Math.** in expression and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Math prefix in an expression.  It's just log(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
var radiance = image.expression(
    ' 0.0003342 * (b10)  + (0.10000) - (0.29)', {
      'b10': image.select('B10'),
    }).rename('radiance');
      

var bt = image.expression(
  '1321.0789/(774.8853/ radiance +1)-273.15',
  {'radiance':radiance}
  );
```